# Is there a native way to install a keyboard layout or input method for the Lao language? I can only find apps and "soft keyboards"

Tags: keyboard, languages, xiaomi, miui, input-methods

I have a Xiaomi Redmi 4A that I bought in China a month or two ago. So it's using MIUI.

It only comes with a few languages and I can't find a way to install others. (Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese, English, Tibetan, and Uyghur.)

I've crossed the border into Laos and want to be able to use Lao on my phone like I can on my laptop.

As a lot of apps etc to download are full of crap of various kinds I don't really trust them as I would a native keyboard/input from Google, Android, Xiaomi, or MIUI.